# Spark SQL Merge query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to `MERGE` two tables using spark sql and getting error with the statement.

The tables are created as external tables pointing to the Azure ADLS storage. The sql is executing using Databricks.

Table 1:

```
Name,Age.Sex
abc,24,M
bca,25,F
```

Table 2:

```
Name,Age,Sex
abc,25,M
acb,25,F
```

The Table 1 is the target table and Table 2 is the source table.
In the table 2 I have one Insert and one update record which needs to be merged with source table 1.

Query:

```
MERGE INTO table1 using table2 ON (table1.name=table2.name)
WHEN MATCHED AND table1.age <> table2.age AND table1.sex<>table2.sex
THEN UPDATE SET table1.age=table2.age AND table1.sex=table2.sex
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT (name,age,sex) VALUES (table2.name,table2.age,table2.sex)
```

Is the spark SQL support merge or is there another way of achieving it ?

Thanks
Sat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To use MERGE you need the Delta Lake option (and associated jars). Then you can use MERGE.
- Otherwise, SQL Merge is not supported by Spark. The Dataframe Writer APIs with own logic are then needed. There are a few different ways to do this. Even with ORC ACID, Spark will not work in this way.